# Ruby on rails 4.2.2, form_for Notification.create(..), trying to add a DB entry without user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to add a database entry with data derrived from an in line ruby function.

The only way I have found to get the entry into my database is with this:

```
<%= form_for Notification.create(:rec_user => bookc.user_id, :snd_user => @user.id, :snd_email => @user.email, :rec_title => bookc.title, :snd_title => booka.title) do |f| %>

     <%= f.submit "Request", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Here is my notifications controller:

```
  class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]


      def create
        @notification = current_user.notifications.build(notification_params)
        if @notification.save
          flash[:success] = "Request sent!"
          redirect_to current_user
        else
          render 'static_pages/notifications'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        Notification.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "Notification Deleted"
        redirect_to current_user 
      end

      private

        def mnotification_params
          params.require(:notification).permit(:content)
        end

    end

<% end %>
```

This function does put the record in the database but then takes me to this URL: https://ifb299-lukemolloy.c9.io/notifications/32  (32 being the id of the new record) This URL is just a page that says something went wrong.

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the logs that follow the POST request from your form?

Comment: That is an odd way of doing things. Why not create the record in the controller?

Comment: I'm quite new to rails and I am not entirely sure how the controllers work